# Checking COM Port Availability in C#

Tags: c#, wmi, serial-port

My C# application populates a `comboBox` with the COM ports found on the system.  I would like the mark the COM ports that are in use as such.  I know that I can use `try` / `catch` blocks to attempt to open every COM port, but I was wondering if there is a more graceful way to do this.  Perhaps using a WMI query?  I am using Microsoft Visual C# 2008 Express Edition (.NET 2.0).  Any thoughts or suggestions you may have would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any other method to do this. Attempting to open them is the way that native code does the same check.

Answer (score 0):

I know this a Old. But there is now a really easy way to do this. You can check if a port is open with:

```
if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
{
    ("Port Open");
}
```